# Error message after photoscene is processed while requesting for download link, Autodesk Forge, Reality Capture API

Tags: autodesk-forge

I get an error message after my photoscene is processed.

The progress message displays 100% but the status is "error".

Here is how it looks:

```
{"Usage":"0.70250296592712","Resource":"\/photoscene\/vPUUyW3cuzXhU0jI9yBXP8PAMArK12hERJC8mCp3ShY","Photoscene":{"photosceneid":"vPUUyW3cuzXhU0jI9yBXP8PAMArK12hERJC8mCp3ShY","progressmsg":"ERROR","progress":"100","scenelink":{},"urn":{},"filesize":{},"resultmsg":{},"filename":{}}}
```

Comment: Can you please add more details on how to reproduce the problem? Also, I'm not sure if this is programming related.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to add missing details (see [mcve] ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Answer (score 0):

We checked the backend log of this job. It looks like it failed due to the condition of the photos submitted. Six (out of 20) photos could not be stitched.
Some tips & guidelines can be found at https://help.autodesk.com/view/RECAP/2018/ENU/?guid=RealityCapture_Photo_UAV_UAS_Drone_Best_Practices_Workflow_and_Use_Cases_html
Unfortunately the service does not update the project with a processing error code currently. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Alternatively, if most of his photos were taken obliquely (from an angle) he could also try using the object scene type (`scenetype=object`),

Comment: Thank you very much for the response. 
The processing worked after recapturing the images and changing scenetype to object. But the issue now is that, the obtained scene link throws an error when trying to access it.

Comment: @Nimalan_Sri sorry, just noticed your reply.. Could you log a new post (or email to forge.help@autodesk.com) with more details of 'obtained scene link throws an error when trying to access it' ? we will follow up further. thank you and happy new year!

Comment: It would be good if the Error could tell you which images can't be stitched. At the moment you just get "Error", which is not very helpful. I just had the same issue as Nimalan_Sri.